# Como consertar erro de Insert em tabela gêneros?

Tags: php, mysql

Como posso consertar o código abaixo?

Ele tira os espaços entre as vírgulas dos gêneros ou seja se eu tenho esses gêneros "ação, aventura, romance" ele coloca assim "ação,aventura,romance" certo? Só que caso eu faça a ordem inversa (assim: "romance, aventura, ação") ou coloque com mais espaços entre as vírgulas de forma alterada ou igual (mais o menos dessa forma: "ação,aventura,  romance" ou "ação,  romance,  aventura") fica dando erro de inserir o mesmo item na tabela da MySQL gêneros.

Como posso fazer no caso não importando a ordem que eu coloque os gêneros ou espaços entre as vírgulas faça o adicionamento único de um só gênero e caso tenha já ele cadastrado na MySQL não volte a adicioná-lo.

Como posso consertar isso?

```
<?php $generoMinusculo = strtolower(trim($_POST["genero"]));
    if ($generoMinusculo) { 
    $generoMinusculo = str_replace(' ,',',',$generoMinusculo);  
    $generoMinusculo = str_replace(' , ',',',$generoMinusculo); 
    $generoMinusculo = str_replace('  ,  ',',',$generoMinusculo);   
    $generoMinusculo = str_replace(' ,  ',',',$generoMinusculo);    
    $generoMinusculo = str_replace('  , ',',',$generoMinusculo);    
    $generos = explode("," , $generoMinusculo); 

foreach ($generos as $item) {
    $Generos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `generos`  WHERE `genero`='".$item."'");
    $verificar = mysql_fetch_array($Generos);
    $verificarGenero =  $verificar["genero"];
    $generoPostado = $item; 
    if ($generoPostado != $verificarGenero){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `generos` SET `genero`='".$item."'");
    }elseif ($generoPostado == $verificarGenero){ }
    else { } } ?>
```

Comment: Se possível, adiciona à pergunta os dados atuais, da tabela, para vermos como está.

Comment: Se você tem gravado `romance, aventura, ação` e vai dar um insert em `aventura`, vai precisar fazer um select nessa tabela e passar os dados para um array com `explode`. Depois basta verificar se `aventura` está no array para poder inserir ou não.

Answer (score 3):

Em primeiro lugar, podemos simplificar seu tratamento da entrada. É sempre recomendável limpar a entrada para previnir contra [injections](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php):

```
$generoMinusculo = strtolower(trim($_POST["genero"]));
if ($generoMinusculo) { 

    // Use array_map aplicar as funções de limpeza em todos os itens  
    $generos = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_map('trim', explode("," , $generoMinusculo))); 

    foreach ($generos as $item) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Quanto a só inserir se o item não existir, sei de algumas opções:

1. `INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS`

   ```
   INSERT INTO GENEROS (genero)
   SELECT '$item' AS genero
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT genero FROM generos WHERE genero = '$item')
   ```
2. `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

   ```
   INSERT INTO GENEROS (genero) VALUES ('$item')
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE genero = genero
   ```
3. `INSERT IGNORE`

   ```
   INSERT IGNORE INTO GENEROS (genero) VALUES ('$item')
   ```

   Nota: O `IGNORE` serve para suprimir os erros, e não para ignorar o `INSERT` como pode parecer

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda.